# undefined variable error in while loop PHP - ACCESS

Tags: php, variables, ms-access, while-loop

I am getting data from couple of queries in a php page. All the loops and queries are working perfectly but I am getting error in the following one.

**ERROR ONE:**

```
$sql_pso_sign="SELECT * FROM Table";
$rs_pso_sign=odbc_exec($conn,$sql_pso_sign);
if (!$rs_pso_sign) {
  exit("Error in SIGNATURE TABLE INFO SQL");
}
 while (odbc_fetch_row($rs_pso_sign)) {

      $psoName = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "NAME");
      $psoSign = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "SIGNATURE");
      $psoDate = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "DATE");

  }

  echo $psoName;
```

the error is Undefined variable: pso_name;

I have copied it from same page other loops which work fine. the working one on same page is

```
$sql_items="SELECT * FROM Table2";
$rs_items=odbc_exec($conn,$sql_items);
if (!$rs_items) {
  exit("Error in table2 SQL");
}
 while (odbc_fetch_row($rs_items)) {

    $calc = odbc_result($rs_items, "ITEMS_CALC");
    $dsd = odbc_result($rs_items, "ITEMS_DSD");
    $wrs = odbc_result($rs_items, "ITEMS_WRS");
    $specs = odbc_result($rs_items, "ITEMS_SPECS");
    $ochk = odbc_result($rs_items, "ITEMS_OTHERS");
    $otxt = odbc_result($rs_items, "ITEMS_OTHERS_TXT");

}
echo $calc;
```

it has become really frustrated I've deleted and pasted same while loops from others and I've put echo checks which do not echo inside while loop of first query.

Any suggestions?

ACTUAL CODE:

```
$sql_pso_sign="SELECT * FROM SIGNATURES_DASO WHERE DASO_NO ='".$daso_no."'";
$rs_pso_sign=odbc_exec($conn,$sql_pso_sign);
if (!$rs_pso_sign) {
  exit("Error in SIGNATURE TABLE INFO SQL");
}
 while (odbc_fetch_row($rs_pso_sign)) {

      $psoName = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "NAME");
      $psoSign = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "SIGNATURE");
      $psoDate = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "DATE");

  }

 echo $psoName;
```

The $daso_no has value in it and i have checked the query is correct

Comment: Fix the syntax errors first.

Comment: the markdown highlighter already shows it (or just maybe a typo)

Comment: Secondly the variable is named `$psoName` and not `$pso_name;` and that's the error you're seeing

Comment: thts just a typo here, its $psoName in echo.

Comment: im using dreamweaver and it says no syntax error.

Comment: Please fix the typos here. We can't tell what's wrong with your script if it's different from what you show.

Comment: Now that you've changed the code in the question, there's no way it could be getting that error. There's no variable `$pso_name` in the code you posted. Are you sure you copied the error correctly? The error message has a line number, please post that line of the script.

Comment: it gives error on the line number that has echo $psoName; that is what the frustrating part is as it should clearly work.

Comment: Are you sure the query is returning any rows? If there are no rows returned, you'll never do the assignment.

Comment: Does the error message really say `pso_name` and not `psoName`? You're not making it easy on us if you keep posting typos instead of pasting the real code and real error message.

Comment: is there a limit of number of queries we can place on one connection or page in access?

Comment: How many rows should the query return? You're reading the results in a loop, but you're only echoing the value from the last one. I suspect it only returns one row, and you don't really need a loop,  but you used `while` because you saw that in examples and thought it was required.

Comment: @barmar, i have posted actual code now. There are rows in the database. i have echoed the query it displays fine. the error message actually says the variable name in the case of actual code i posted it says $psoName; undefined. it should return just 1 row. can you show code if we just want one row to return.

Comment: I showed the code in my answer, what more do you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that the query is returning a row:

```
$sql_pso_sign="SELECT * FROM SIGNATURES_DASO WHERE DASO_NO ='".$daso_no."'";
$rs_pso_sign=odbc_exec($conn,$sql_pso_sign);
if (!$rs_pso_sign) {
  exit("Error in SIGNATURE TABLE INFO SQL");
}
if (odbc_fetch_row($rs_pso_sign)) {

    $psoName = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "NAME");
    $psoSign = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "SIGNATURE");
    $psoDate = odbc_result($rs_pso_sign, "DATE");

    echo $psoName;
} else {
    echo "$daso_no not found.";
}
```

Notice that you don't need to use a `while` loop if the query is only supposed to return one row.

Comment: working perfectly now. Thank You. One question. if we want one record while loop is not the best approach?

Comment: Right. A while loop is for repeatedly processing all the records. It's unnecessary if there's only one record.

Answer (score 1):

You wrong named your variable

```
$pso_name;
```

Change it to

```
$psoName;
```

Comment: The missing quotes must be a copying error, otherwise the script wouldn't even run.

Comment: Yeah you right :) I edited his post and mine

Comment: which missing quotes are you talking about? @barmar?

Comment: @Alz When you posted the question, you wrote `$sql_pso_sign="SELECT * FROM Table;` -- the closing quotes were missing there.

Comment: that was a typo, my bad.

Comment: Why don't you paste the actual code and error message, instead of retyping it. Then you can't make typos, and we can help you with your problem.